# Delete duplicate values

Tags: sql, oracle

I hava a table emp, I wish to delete the duplicate values.
The subquery is good.

```
SELECT ename 
                 FROM   emp 
                 GROUP  BY ename 
                 HAVING Count(empno) > 1
```

But when I do the delete operation its deleting all the lines. I don't understand what mistake I'm doing.

```
DELETE FROM emp 
WHERE  ename IN (SELECT ename 
                 FROM   emp 
                 GROUP  BY ename 
                 HAVING Count(empno) > 1);
```

Answer (score 3):

It deletes all ENAMEs, not only duplicates (i.e. it doesn't leave one row). Try something like

Table contents at beginning:

```
SQL> select * From temp order by id;

        ID ENAME
---------- ----------
         1 Little
         2 Little          --> duplicate ENAME
         3 Foot
```

Deleting:

```
SQL> delete from temp a
  2  where a.rowid > (select min(b.rowid)
  3                   from temp b
  4                   where b.ename = a.ename
  5                  );

1 row deleted.
```

Result;

```
SQL> select * From temp order by id;

        ID ENAME
---------- ----------
         1 Little
         3 Foot

SQL>
```

Comment: thanks for you comments but its not deleting any lines

Comment: Then you're doing something wrong. I edited my answer and added an example which shows that such a principle *works* if you use it properly.